# Uncaught TypeError: $.backstretch is not a function

Tags: jquery

I want to add `backstretch` in my code.
This is the script:

```html
<script>
    // To attach Backstrech as the body's background 
    jquery.backstretch("/form-3/assets/img/backgrounds/1.jpg");

    // You may also attach Backstretch to a block-level element 
    jquery.(".foo").backstretch("/form-3/assets/img/backgrounds/1.jpg");

    // If your element defines a background image with CSS, you can omit the argement altogether 
    //$(".foo").backstretch();

    // Or, to start a slideshow, just pass in an array of images 
    jquery.(".foo").backstretch([
        "/form-3/assets/img/backgrounds/1.jpg",
        "/form-3/assets/img/backgrounds/2.jpg",
        "/form-3/assets/img/backgrounds/1@2x.jpg"    
    ], {duration: 4000});

</script> 

//I have included the scripts here
<script src="/form-3/assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/form-3/assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="/form-3/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/form-3/assets/js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>

<script src="/form-3/assets/js/jquery.backstretch.js"></script>
<script src="/form-3/assets/js/scripts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
```

I want to dynamically change the images as we open this html page. But It is saying

> `Uncaught type error. $backstretch is not a function.`

How can we include it? Or are there any other ways to change the pictures dynamically?

Comment: why you have included jquery multiple times ?  include it only once at top of other js files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are including `scripts` after initializing the `plugin` which is the actual reason for the above `error`. Just move all the scripts before any `js`

```
<script src="/form-3/assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/form-3/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/form-3/assets/js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
<script src="/form-3/assets/js/jquery.backstretch.js"></script>
<script src="/form-3/assets/js/scripts.js"></script>

<script>
  // To attach Backstrech as the body's background 
  jquery.backstretch("/form-3/assets/img/backgrounds/1.jpg");

  // You may also attach Backstretch to a block-level element 
  jquery.(".foo").backstretch("/form-3/assets/img/backgrounds/1.jpg");

  // If your element defines a background image with CSS, you can omit the argement altogether 
  //$(".foo").backstretch();

  // Or, to start a slideshow, just pass in an array of images 
  jquery.(".foo").backstretch([
    "/form-3/assets/img/backgrounds/1.jpg",
    "/form-3/assets/img/backgrounds/2.jpg",
    "/form-3/assets/img/backgrounds/1@2x.jpg"    
  ], {duration: 4000});

</script>
```

**Do not include multiple reference to same file as in you have included reference to `jquery-1.11.1.min.js` multiple times.**

Also I feel that these lines `jquery.(".foo")` have to be `jquery(".foo")`. No `.` after `jquery`

Comment: @rajshree Anytime.. Happy coding.. Do mark it as answer if it helped.. :)